# COM Class factory error 80040154 when Opening Get Directory Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I know the usual cause for this issue is related to the platform that a component is compiled to and I have had the problem in the past.  However this is a report from a single user and occurs any time he tries to open either a dialog to select a file or directory.  I am not using any fancy components here just the standard one.  The relevant lines in one of the stack traces are:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154.    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog.CreateVistaDialog()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialogVista(IntPtr hWndOwner)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hWndOwner)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog()    at
>   ScruffyDuck.AirportDesignEditor.MainForm.getOpenFileInfo(String
>   initialDirectory, String filter)

I searched my registry for this CLSID and came up with

> %SystemRoot%\System32\comdlg32.dll

Which is no a surprise I suppose.  I assume, since there are many other users out there who do not have this problem that is must relate to the users setup.  I would appreciate any ideas on how to advise him in this case.

Many thanks

Comment: Is your App run in `MTAThread`? Look for the `main()` method, then see its attributes, should be `[MTAThread]` there or `[STAThread]`.

Comment: It is in [STATThread] Always has been and we have never seen this before.  As far as I know it is reported by a single user out of 30,000 or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing now, since this is no programming question, so don't -1 me if I didn't help, just giving some ideas... :P

Problem here is that the system can't make COM object out of the COM class specified by that CLSID. This can happen for many reasons:

- Library `comdlg32.dll` is not registered, try to register it with `regsvr32 comdlg32.dll`
- System accont doesn't have full control (permission) over the registry key that holds CLSID `{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}`. You can check that by navigating (or searching registry) to that key, right click on it, and by selecting `Permissions...` give SYSTEM account full control over it.
- Try the above for the Administrator account as well.
- Library `comdlg32.dll` is corrupted. This can happen if the spyware or some other malicious program tried to hook itself to the Open File or Browse Directory dialogs and so has modified the lib... in that case, you have to reinstall the lib... or windows. To check is the lib ok, make the MD5 hash of it, and compare with the MD5 hash of the lib on a working system. They should be identical.

Well, hope I helped. :)

Comment: regsvr32 won't work because comdlg32.dll doesn't export DllRegisterServer (it's part of the OS, and should never have the need to be independently installed). I agree that this is not much of a programming issue, and probably a corrupted OS installation or some bad 3rd party. If nothing else works, I'd try a repair installation of Windows.

Comment: @eran Of course this is not my system.  Would I be right that if the user has problems with this in my app then it would also arise in other apps?

Comment: @cipi  Many thanks and that is helpful.  I am waiting on the user to respond to my email since this came from an automated log upload.  It may well be that his system is corrupted.

Comment: @ScruffyDuck, I can't say for sure, but I'd expect that user to have all sorts of problems, not only when using your app.

Comment: @eran - I can believe it - he has not responded to my email so I will park this now until he does.  Thanks for the help