# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, com

Using .Net 4.0 / WPF Application / C#

I have the following piece of code in my application, which opens a FileDialog when the `Select` button is clicked.

```
OpenFileDialog fdgSelectFile;
bool? dialogResult;

try
{
    fdgSelectFile = new OpenFileDialog {DefaultExt = FileDialogDefaultExt, Filter = FileDialogFilter};
    dialogResult = fdgSelectFile.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
    {
        SelectedFilePath = fdgSelectFile.FileName;
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

This piece of code works in other machines, but not in my machine. It just throws an exception - as below - when the `Select` button is clicked upon.

```
2015-04-28 14:33:47,453 [1] ERROR XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.ViewModels.UploadViewModel - SelectFile - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040111): Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog.CreateVistaDialog()
   at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.RunVistaDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)
   at Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)
   at Microsoft.Win32.CommonDialog.ShowDialog()
   at XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.ViewModels.UploadViewModel.SelectFile(Object param) in c:\XXXX\XXXX\Client\XXXX.XXXX.XXXX\ViewModels\UploadViewModel .cs:line 176
```

---

Finding out the error is caused by `comdlg32.dll` from `Microsoft.Win32` namespace, inside `PresentationFramework.dll` assembly, I queried the Registry for this CLS ID

```
reg query HKCR\CLSID | find /i "{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}"
```

and here is what it says

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}

---

I have also tried the following

1. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602256/80040111-classfactory-cannot-supply-requested-class-exception-from-hresult-0x8) SO Post, I tried to register the `dll`, but it came back saying

   > [Window Title]  RegSvr32
   >
   > [Content]   The module "comdlg32.dll" was loaded but the entry-point
   >   DllRegisterServer was not found.
   >
   > Make sure that "comdlg32.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try
   >   again.
   >
   > [OK]
2. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297918/com-class-factory-error-80040154-when-opening-get-directory-dialog) SO Post, I tried changing the `Permissions`, but no luck

---

Is there any way this can be resolved apart from re-imaging the machine or re-installing Windows?

If this helps : I have .Net FrameWork v3.5/ v4.0 / v4.5.1 & v4.5.2 installed in my machine and the `PresentationFramework.dll` is available in all locations inside the folders

```
v3.5   : C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client
v4.0   : C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
v4.5   : C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5
v4.5.1 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1
v4.5.2 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2
```

Comment: @HansPassant, the same thing works in other machines. I am able to open the file open dialog box from other apps too

Comment: @HansPassant - I was able to reproduce this issue by turning off Visual Themes - it looks like a bug in the WPF wrapper for the OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog

Comment: Are you running your project from a network path/share? Try and move/copy the entire source over to C drive and run it from there.

Answer (score 5):

Discarding the possibility that the Windows installation is broken, this is actually a rather insidious problem that is caused by "Visual Themes" being turned off in Windows 7 and above.

To reproduce it you can take a working WPF application and modify it's compatibility settings (righ-click on the .exe in Windows Explorer, then select Preferences and from the Compatibiltiy tab, check "Disable Visual Themes"). Then, try running the application and you'll notice it starts crashing when you try to show an OpenFileDialog or a SaveFileDialog.

Visual Themes may be turned off at the OS level as well (when using a high contrast theme for instance) and they are usually turned off in Terminal Services sessions, or when desktop sharing via WebEx or some other desktop sharing applications.

Unfortunately I don't have a solution yet but based on reading through MSDN it looks like Microsoft is saying you should "provide an alternative code path" when desktop composition and visual themes are off - whatever that means.

Internally, the OpenFileDialog's implementation has a method that attempts to initialize an instance of the open file dialog COM control which fails when Visual Themes are off

```
[SecurityCritical, SecurityTreatAsSafe]
internal override IFileDialog CreateVistaDialog()
{
    new SecurityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted).Assert();
    return (IFileDialog) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("DC1C5A9C-E88A-4dde-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7")));
}
```

Comment: There can be workarounds, such as using the old XP style dialogs. I wrote about them in a blog post, https://blog.lextudio.com/openfiledialog-crashes-with-comexception-0x80040111-f51e18d1ab89

Comment: I run into the same problem in window 10 when turning on 'high contrast'. When I turn off 'hight contrast', it is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using `SaveFileDialog`.

Make sure to use `System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog`, and **not** `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog`

Answer (score 1):

A note on the answer to use `System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog`; be sure to set the property `AutoUpgradeEnabled = False`.

There is a high-contrast mode in Windows 10, if the user has it on and you don't set this option, you will get this error.

Caveat: The control will look like something from Windows XP, but at least it will still work.